# setup multiple webservers on network

Tags: linux, server, webserver

i have 2 webservers (windows and linux(ubuntu))

I am using a static IP and point all of my sites using defaults webserver(windows) port 80

I just setup a linux server for certain sites but need to know how I can route specific domains to that particular server on port 8080

I currently have this working
http://judsonlinux.dyndns.org:8080/

but again I need to know how to point specific domains to this. I have read some things about using reverse proxy on the windows server. Is this the way to go?

Thanks

UPDATE: I got the rewrite working but for some reason its not pulling up the site. Its going to the default apache server page.

here is my conf...

[image: screenshot]

Ther is an index page in public folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after setting up the linux server, I had to change the default port on linux to 8080, then added this on my main server(80) in windows. It now works.  a website in IIS on windows. Then used the URL rewrite rule as follows.

[image: screen]

Answer (score -1):

You can write rewrite rules for the domains.

ex: in apache

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1.org$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://judsonlinux.dyndns.org:8080/$1 [P,L]
```

ex: IIS

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Fail bad requests">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect from blog">
      <match url="^domain/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="www.d.com:8080/{R:2}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
      <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx:8080?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

ref:[IIS Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: Very useful, please see my comments (updates)

Comment: Have you enabled the site using a2ensite ? try disabling the default site with a2disite command and reloading the apache2 server.

Comment: For your reference http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2011/01/07/ubuntu-how-to-enable-or-disable-an-apache2-site-virtual-host/